# Bot said: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

Tags: python, azure, botframework, chatbot

I have a Microsoft bot framework chatbot and when I run it locally it works fine and everything goes perfectly but when I publish it to Azure and try to test it in web chat there is an error appears as in the image below and the error is that the bot can't access a file in the project files.

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> FullName(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var activity = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply("");
        activity.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions();
        
        var text = stepContext.Context.Activity.Text;
        
        if (text != "القائمة الرئيسية")
        {
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllText(@"OtherFiles/Appointment.txt",String.Empty);
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"OtherFiles\Appointment.txt",true))
                {                    
                    writer.Write(string.Empty);
                    writer.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(e.ToString());
            }
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync("ادخل الاسم كامل لو سمحت");
        }
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(Actions.Prompt, new PromptOptions()
            {
                Prompt = activity
            });
       
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcxVw.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `File.WriteAllText` and `StreamWriter` classes in C# will create the file if it doesn't exist. However, they will throw an exception if the directory specified in the path doesn't exist. So, you need to make sure that the directory (`OtherFiles` in your case) exists before attempting to write to the file.

The error message is telling us that the bot is unable to find the file `Appointment.txt` in the `OtherFiles` directory when running on Azure.

This is likely due to differences in the file system between your local environment and the Azure environment.

Could you please try the following suggestion?

1. **Check File Path**: Make sure that the file path is correct and that the `OtherFiles` directory and `Appointment.txt` file exist in the Azure environment. You may need to upload these manually or include them in your deployment package.
2. **Use Relative Paths**: Instead of using hard-coded paths, use relative paths to make your code more portable.

   For example:

   ```cs
   string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "OtherFiles", "Appointment.txt");
   ```

I guess my suggestion would be to modify your code to dynamically check if the directory exists and create it if it doesn't. This ensures that your code is robust enough to handle both local and Azure environments.

Example:

```cs
string dirPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "OtherFiles");
string filePath = Path.Combine(dirPath, "Appointment.txt");

// Check if the directory exists, create if not
if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
}

File.WriteAllText(filePath, String.Empty);
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
{                    
    writer.Write(string.Empty);
    writer.WriteLine(text);
}
```